# How do I input a 2D array in C?

Tags: c

I've been trying to make a program that counts the  number of characters in an inputted text, not counting spaces. I know I have to do it with a 2D array, but when I input the set of words, my loop here only counts the characters in the first word.

Here is the main code:

```
char text[400][40];
int charNum = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;


printf("input string: \n");
scanf("%s", &text);
while(text[i] != '\0'){
    while(text[i][j] != '\0'){
        printf("\n\nword: %s\n", text[i]);
        printf("\n\nchar:%c\n", text[i][j]);      
        charNum = charNum + j;
        j++;
        printf("J= %d\n", j);
    }
    i++;
}
```

How do I input the 2D array so the loop can read each string in it?

Comment: Hint: `scanf("%s", &text);`is outrigjht wrong. Check the data types.

Comment: But isnt every string declared as a char, and has %s in scanf?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211087/how-to-fill-a-2d-array-in-c-with-user-input-values)
solution can be found

Comment: Can you provide a possible input? and what output you expect from it. We can't help if you dont even show that.

Comment: sadsad asdasdasd asdasdasdasd

Comment: Edit your question; don't try adding comments.  Especially ones where formatting would be helpful, like the input.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have declared the input to be stored in char text[400][40]; Which means that you can store 400 words of 40 character length each. When you are inputing your word if you are using scanf, scanf will only take the input only till the first space it encounters. so use fgets for reading input words. 
example :
text[0] = "john";
text[1] = " xyzxyz xyz";
you will be able to read both formats using fgets.

Comment: But isnt fgets only used for getting a string out of a file?

Comment: "*of 40 character length each.*", no, not exactly, but of 39 `char`s only, as C strings require one more `char` to store the `0`-termination.

Comment: the file can also be stdin and stdout. it looks only for the file pointer and the file pointer can be initialized to the standard input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) to read the input strings, and [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to parse the strings at each space.

Something like this could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMWORDS 400
#define WORDLEN 40
#define BUFFSIZE 100

int
main(void) {
    char text[NUMWORDS][WORDLEN];
    char line[BUFFSIZE], *word;
    size_t slen, count = 0;
    int i;

    printf("Enter some words: ");
    if (fgets(line, BUFFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading into buffer.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    slen = strlen(line);
    if (slen > 0) {
        if (line[slen-1] == '\n') {
            line[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Exceeded buffer length of %d.\n", BUFFSIZE);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (!*line) {
        printf("No words entered.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    word = strtok(line, " ");
    while (word != NULL) {
        if (strlen(word) >= WORDLEN) {
            printf("\nYour word \"%s\" is longer than word size limit: %d\n", 
                      word,  WORDLEN);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(text[count], word);
        count++;
        word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

    if (count > NUMWORDS) {
        printf("Too many words entered.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nYour array of strings:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("text[%d] = %s\n", i, text[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Enter some words: sadsad asdasdasd asdasdasdasd
```

Output:

```
Your array of strings:
text[0] = sadsad
text[1] = asdasdasd
text[2] = asdasdasdasd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the characters of input text? I would have done something like this (the if(*s != 32) is to not count the spaces, ASCII "space" = decimal 32):

```
int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    char input[200] = "This is an input string";
    size = mystrlen(input);
    printf("size=%d", str);
    return 0

}

int mystrlen(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*s++) {
        if (*s != 32)
            i++;
    }
    return i;
}
output: size = 19;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply because scanf read until the 1st space.
You have to use gets here.
This for a simple caracter counting without spaces:

```
char str [100];
int i=0,cpt=0;
printf ("Enter some words: ");
gets (str);
While(str [i]!='\0'){
    if (str [i]!=' '){
        cpt++;
    }
    i++;
}

printf ("Size: %d",cpt);
```

Comment: Do not never use `gets()`, its evil and not part of C any more. Use `fgets()` instead,

Answer (score 0):

First of all the scanf("%s", &text); you are using will not read any spaces. It will read only till the first space is encountered in the name. use scanf("%[^/n]s", &text); instead to read the name with spaces.
The way your are reading the 2D array is wrong. The simple way is to use a  for loop.

example:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   scanf ("%[^/n]s,text[i]);
}
```